# Why does this await outside async function work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

So I've been fiddling with `javascript` and found a strange behavior, for now anyway.

Given these snippets

```js
database.js

import MongoDB from "mongodb";

const MongoClient = MongoDB.MongoClient;

const uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?poolSize=20&writeConcern=majority"

const mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true });

let instance;
const getInstance = async () => {
    if (!instance) {
        instance = mongoClient.connect();
    }
    return instance;
}

export const client = await getInstance();
```

```js
services.js

import { client } from "./database"

//return array of items
function getUserRecommendationItems(username) {
    const shopifyDb = client.db('Shopify');
    const product = shopifyDb.collection('product');
    return product.find().toArray();
}

export default { getUserRecommendationItems }
```

```js
index.js

import services from "./services"

(async () => {
    const products = await services.getUserRecommendationItems();
    console.log(products);
})();
```

When I remove await in `database.js`, it throws an error because it needs to wait for the client to  connect first.

My question is, why can I access `client` in `service.js` without putting it inside async function?
Does it mean export and import are async functions under the hood?

Comment: From what I understand, you are already exporting the fulfilled promise (client) from your database.js. So when you access client in service.js you are using that object. Also, what is the reason you have added index.js in the question? It is not there in description.

Comment: @TusharShahi thanks for the reply, I added index.js just to make my question full interm of context, but still that leave the main question. I've tried to move the await inside getInstance function, instead I got `client.db is not a function` error. which again very strange, as `mongoClient.connect()` is a promise, It should have worked.

Comment: _"I got client.db is not a function error. which again very strange"_ - async functions return a promise - when you remove the `await` before the `getInstance` function, you are exporting a promise in pending state. You need to either `await` client or chain a `then` method call to use the value with which it is fulfilled. Calling `db` method on a pending promise is the cause of the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like your environment supports [the top-level await proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await). The proposal is currently at stage 4 which means "finished" and can be included in the specs officially. But support may still vary.

[Quoting the proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await#solution-top-level-await):

> Top-level `await` lets us rely on the module system itself to handle all of these promises, and make sure that things are well-coordinated. The above example could be simply written and used as follows:
>
> ```js
> // awaiting.mjs
> import { process } from "./some-module.mjs";
> const dynamic = import(computedModuleSpecifier);
> const data = fetch(url);
> export const output = process((await dynamic).default, await data);
> ```
>
> ```js
> // usage.mjs
> import { output } from "./awaiting.mjs";
> export function outputPlusValue(value) { return output + value }
>
> console.log(outputPlusValue(100));
> setTimeout(() => console.log(outputPlusValue(100), 1000);
> ```
>
> None of the statements in `usage.mjs` will execute until the `await`s in `awaiting.mjs` have had their Promises resolved, so the race condition is avoided by design. This is an extension of how, if `awaiting.mjs` didn't use top-level `await`, none of the statements in `usage.mjs` will execute until `awaiting.mjs` is loaded and all of its statements have executed.

Because you have a top-level `await` in `database.js` then `services.js` will only execute when that module has had its `client` promise resolved.

Comment: Ah I see now, the javascript documentationt did mention it `however it can be used on its own with JavaScript modules.` which include top level await. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules
Thank You.